# LINQ GroupBy to get Name and A Count

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm a little confused on how to use a GroupBy in Linq.  I need to display the name of a Product and Count it's offers, I've come up with this

```
var context = new Model.Entities();
var query = from p in Product
            join o in Offers on p.Prod_ID equals o.Prod_ID
            orderby o.Prod_ID
            select new { Name = p.Name, Offers = o.Prod_ID.Count()};
var products = query.ToList();
```

Now I can't simply have

```
Offers = o.Prod_ID.Count()
```

How do I display a row with a Product Name and also the Count of it's offers?

Comment: btw [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C) is nice article on Linq query with examples in linq and sql and results showing each type of joins

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a group join instead:

```
var query = from p in Product
            join o in Offers on p.Prod_ID equals o.Prod_ID into offers
            orderby p.Prod_ID
            select new { Name = p.Name, Offers = offers.Count() };
```

Now after the `join` clause, you've got two range variables in scope:

- `p` (the product)
- `offers` (the offers for that product)

So I've changed the ordering to be on `p.Prod_ID` - and then just counted the offers in the `select` clause.

Note that this way you'll still get a result for products with no offers, whereas if you were doing a straight inner join, those would be lost entirely.